# cfquery.recordcount returns 0 on a cfdirectory, but only on windows

Tags: coldfusion, coldfusion-9

I have a query on a directory in Coldfusion 9. Why does this code run on mac giving the expected result but not on windows?

```
<cfoutput>
<cfset fileLocation = "d:/tmp"> <!--- On mac set to /tmp --->
<cfdirectory
        action = "list"
        directory = "#fileLocation#"
        name = "files"
        >
Files found #files.recordcount# <br/>
<cfquery name="dir" dbtype="query">
        select  *
        from    files
        where   directory = <cfqueryparam value = "#fileLocation#">
</cfquery>
Query gives #dir.recordcount#
</cfoutput>
```

Both machines run Coldfusion 10 and the directory exists. The output on the mac is

```
Files found 5
Query gives 5
```

and on windows

```
Files found 5
Query gives 0
```

Am I missing the obvious?

Comment: did you try to <Cfdump var="#files#"> right after your cfdirectory to see what the return looks like and then compare?

Comment: Can you CFDUMP the Windows version? Does your CF Service have permission to read from d:\tmp?

Comment: Try to match "d:\temp" on windows in your query of queries. Since cfdirectory returns the directory in windows notation, d:/temp won't be found in your query.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ah my guess is windows reports the directory name as `D:\tmp` instead of the other slash: `D:/tmp`.  Which is why your `directory = #filelocation#` isn't returning any matches. You might be able to make this more platform independent [as described in this article](http://blogs.adobe.com/cantrell/archives/2003/03/making_your_col_1.html).

I could have sworn there was a built-in function for this in CF now, but I can't seem to find it.

Comment: That is it. Didn't expect it to be like that but makes sense. Thanks! However as the underlying implementation is Java, this should not matter. As you can see, it works for the cfdirectory. Something dodgy is happening here within CF...

Comment: *as the underlying implementation is Java, this should not matter* That is not where the issue occurs. Java has no problem with the slashes, it is being dropped by the query filter. Since you are using an equality comparison, the difference in value should definitely be respected. After all the values are *not* equal. So zero (0) records is the correct result.

Comment: on Windows based systems, the 'direction' of the slash should not matter for finding resources. Windows recognizes '/' and '\' as path delimiters. As Leigh pointed out, the issue is more likely the comparison of 'D:/temp' to what is likely 'D:\temp'.